# How to write a find query to compare two fields in Express and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to compare two fields using Express. I have tried my best but I am getting errors.

I have enclosed my schema, routes, and controller. These are API calls and I want to know how to pass two fields from AngularJS `$http.get` method. I have enclosed my AngularJS controller with the API call also

Schema:

```
var PromusageSchema = new Schema({

    StoreID: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    StoreName: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
});

mongoose.model('Promusage', PromusageSchema);
```

Controller

```
exports.promusageByEMAIL = function(req, res, next, id) { 
    Promusage.find({customer_Email:id})
        .populate('user', 'displayName')
        .exec(function(err, promusage) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            if (!promusage) return next(new Error('Failed to load Promusage ' + id));
        req.promusage = promusage;
        next();
    });
};
```

Routes

```
app.route('/promusages1/:promusageEmail')
    .get(promusages.read)
    .put(promusages.update)
    .delete(promusages.delete);

    // Finish by binding the Promusage middleware
app.param('promusageEmail', promusages.promusageByEMAIL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to send information to an API, you should be using `$http.post` or similar. `$http.get` is for retrieving data, not sending data.

That said, it looks like you're actually trying to get information from the API. However, your GET request doesn't appear to be mapped to a usable function. Should this: `.get(promusages.read)` be this: `.get(promusages.find)` in your routes?

That's the only function you've defined. Although it's hard to tell since I'm not really sure what `Promusage` is here.